# How to position a view to the border using Linear Layout

Tags: android, layout, view

I need to put my view in the border so it will be in the far left of the layout and want this be applied to all different phone's sizes!?

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="285dp"
        android:text="@string/textView"
        android:textSize="28sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now this code outputs the following
[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhQZv.png), I need to do this without using margin to match all phones sizes

Comment: let upload an image prototype for this case plz, i'll help you.

Comment: done, thx for ur help :D

Comment: Try using constraint layout instead https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add this `android:layout_gravity="right"` to `TextView` and 
`android:orientation="vertical"` to your `LinearLayout` .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"      
        android:text="@string/textView"
        android:textSize="28sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I hope it will work with you .